# javapoet how do I create a static import

Tags: java, javapoet

How do I create a static import using JavaPoet?

The code I'm trying to generate looks like this:

```
import static com.test.Types.*;
```

Comment: There is an open issue related to it: https://github.com/square/javapoet/issues/73

Comment: Cool - I did manage to work around it but the code isn't as pretty as it might be with a static import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way, but there is an open issue related to it: https://github.com/square/javapoet/issues/73

Answer (score 5):

For the record: `static import` is supported since [1.5.0](https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

See [JavaFileTest](https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/master/src/test/java/com/squareup/javapoet/JavaFileTest.java) for example usages.